# Can insert our data of places in google places api?

Tags: android, location-based-service, google-places-api

Many of you has worked on LBS application in android and also used the Google Places API web service for the information. And you may also noticed that the data for India is not accurate means many of places that you know are not their on the map. So my question is that is there any way that you can add your database to Google's Places API Web service in the form of XML/JSON? If yes then please let me know how it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Users Place Report

**User Place Reports**

Place Report requests are used to add new Places, or delete existing ones.
  New Places will be available immediately in Place Searches initiated by your
  application, and will enter the moderation queue
  to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added Place will not be available
  to other applications until it has been approved by the moderation process.

Places that have been added by your application can also be deleted, until
  they have been moderated. Once moderated and added into the full Place
  Search results, a Place can no longer be deleted. Places that are not
  accepted by the moderation process will continue to be visible to the
  application that submitted them.

**Place Report Requests**

**Adding a Place**

A Place Report add request is an HTTP POST request similar to the example
  below:

```
  POST https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/<strong>json</strong>?
            sensor=<var>true_or_false</var>&key=<var>api_key</var> HTTP/1.1
  Host: maps.googleapis.com

  {
         "location": {
         "lat": -33.8669710,
         "lng": 151.1958750
      },
      "accuracy": 50,
      "name": "Google Shoes!",
      "types": ["shoe_store"],
      "language": "en-AU"
  }
```